# if else in trigger in sql

Tags: sql, if-statement, triggers

I m trying to create after insert trigger with if else statement.I can do it without if else, but get error with it.
So, in table 'booking' there is a column customer_id. There is a table customer, where i have a column 'type'. Depending on the value in this column i want add a row to booking_status table, but i get error in syntax. I m just learning sql, please, help if you can.

```
AFTER INSERT ON booking
FOR EACH ROW 
IF (SELECT type FROM customer WHERE ID=customer_id) = 'not trust'
BEGIN
INSERT INTO booking_status (id, status_name, booking_id) VALUES(NEW.booking_number, 'Checking', NEW.booking_number)
END
ELSE
INSERT INTO booking_status (id, status_name, booking_id) VALUES(NEW.booking_number, 'Approved', NEW.booking_number);
```

Comment: You're missing `THEN` and `END IF`.

Comment: You have tagged this with both mysql and sql server. The syntax is very different for each DBMS. Which one is it?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html for MySQL `IF` syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `IF` syntax is incorrect. You need `THEN` before the statements to be executed when the condition is true, you need `END IF;` at the end of it, and you need `;` at the end of each statement. You don't need `BEGIN/END` when there's just a single statement in the `THEN` clause.

```
IF (SELECT type FROM customer WHERE ID=customer_id) = 'not trust'
THEN 
    INSERT INTO booking_status (id, status_name, booking_id) VALUES(NEW.booking_number, 'Checking', NEW.booking_number);
ELSE
    INSERT INTO booking_status (id, status_name, booking_id) VALUES(NEW.booking_number, 'Approved', NEW.booking_number);
ENDIF;
```

But don't need an `IF` statement, you can use the `IF` function in a single `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO booking_status(id, status_name, booking_id)
VALUES (NEW.booking_number, 
        IF((SELECT type FROM customer WHERE ID=customer_id) = 'not trust', 'Checking', 'Approved'),
        NEW.booking_number);
```